# Matching a pattern in a list of strings and returning a list of indexes

Tags: python, regex, list, filter

I want to do the following in python:

```
Input list: ['abc', 'def', 'abx', 'cfd', 'nab', 'fdd', 'aadsd_ab']
Input pattern: 'ab'
Output: Return [0,2,4,6], i.e a list of indexes for every entry in input list that contains input pattern.
```

In this case 'abc', 'abx', 'nab', 'aadsd_ab' contain the pattern 'ab' so return the respective indexes [0, 2, 4, 6]
What is the simplest way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension like so:

```
>>> words = ['abc', 'def', 'abx', 'cfd', 'nab', 'fdd', 'aadsd_ab']
>>> [idx for idx, word in enumerate(words) if 'ab' in word]
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use enumerate, but a list comprehension is also great.

```
l = ['abc', 'def', 'abx', 'cfd', 'nab', 'fdd', 'aadsd_ab']
l_idx = []
for idx, value in enumerate(l):
    if 'ab' in value:
        l_idx.append(idx)
print l_idx
```

`l_idx`  contains the values you were looking for. Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

If want to use `regex` just for more control over the search

```
>>>l = ['abc', 'def', 'abx', 'cfd', 'nab', 'fdd', 'aadsd_ab']
>>>lst = []
>>>for i in l:
    if re.search(".*ab.*", i, re.IGNORECASE):
        lst.append(l.index(i))
>>>lst
>>>[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Explanation:
for every element in list `l` find if it matches the pattern `.*ab.*` if matches then get the index of that element and append it to the second list i.e. `lst`.
regex pattern means find all `ab` that have any character before and after.